# Using GTM to stop link click from propagating and changing href without an event listener

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to fire Facebook pixels among my other analytics scripts. Without getting into too much detail, what I want to do is the following:

1. Have a trigger for whenever a link is clicked and a cookie has been written.

   - If said cookie is written, then fire a custom html tag.
2. That custom html tag will check to see if the link is an outbound link.

   - If link is outbound:

     1. Stop the link from propagating
     2. then either append "?fb=1" or "&fb=1" depending on if a query string has already been written.
     3. Then redirect to new url with appended string.
   - If link is not outbound, do nothing

My custom html tag code:

```js
<script>
  var element = {{Click Element}};;
  
  var linkclickurl = '{{Click URL}}';
  
  alert('Click URL is ' + linkclickurl + '. Hostname is {{Page Hostname}}');
  
  // Check if hostname is contained in linkclickurl
  if(linkclickurl.indexOf("{{Page Hostname}}") > -1) {
    alert('Not outbound link');
  }
  else {
    // Check if query string already exists
    if(linkclickurl.indexOf("?") > -1) {
      window.location.href =  linkclickurl + '&fb=1';
      alert('Found a query');
    }
    else {
      window.location.href =  linkclickurl + '?fb=1';
      alert('Found no query');
    }
  }
</script>
```

So my current problem is that I don't know how to stop the link from propagating after the link click. I'm changing the href after the fact which does nothing as the page will redirect to the original link.

Is there a way to stop the link from propagating if it is outbound and then switch it to the updated version?

Comment: Why not fire this on page load, and change all the links then, rather then trying to stop the link from propagating?

Answer (score 0):

Taking @sdhaus advice, I was able to do this with the following script:

```js
function updateLinks(parameter, value)
{

   var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   var includeDomains = self.location.host;
   
   for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
   {
       if(links[i].href != "#" && links[i].href != "/" && links[i].href != "" && links[i].href != window.location) //Ignore links with empty src attribute, linking to site root, or anchor tags (#)
       {
           var updateLink = true;           
           
           if(links[i].href.toLowerCase().indexOf(includeDomains.toLowerCase()) != -1) //Domain of current link is included i the includeDomains array.  Update Required...
           {
             updateLink = false;
           }           
       
           if(!updateLink)
           {
               //Do nothing - link is internal
           }
           else
           {
               var queryStringComplete = "";
               var paramCount = 0;
           
               var linkParts = links[i].href.split("?");
               
               if(linkParts.length > 1) // Has Query String Params
               {
                   queryStringComplete = "?";
               
                   var fullQString = linkParts[1];
                   var paramArray = fullQString.split("&");    
                   var found = false;
                   
                   for (j=0;j<paramArray.length;j++)
                   {
                       
                       var currentParameter = paramArray[j].split("=");
                       
                       if(paramCount > 0)
                           queryStringComplete = queryStringComplete + "&";
                       
                       if(currentParameter[0] == parameter) //Parameter exists in url, refresh value
                        {
                            queryStringComplete = queryStringComplete + parameter + "=" + value;
                            found = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            queryStringComplete = queryStringComplete + paramArray[j]; //Not related parameter - re-include in url
                        }
                       
                        paramCount++;
                   }
                   
                   if(!found) //Add new param to end of query string
                       queryStringComplete = queryStringComplete + "&" + parameter + "=" + value;
               }
               else
               {
                   queryStringComplete = "?" + parameter + "=" + value;
               }
                   
               links[i].href = links[i].href.split("?")[0] + queryStringComplete;        
           }
       }
       else
       {
           //Do nothing
       }
   }
}
```